# Can I be the full Administrator user in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

How to completely change my Account to super user or "Administrator" in Windows 7?

In my **Control Panel**, it says that my account is in the "Administrator" group, but when I type `net user` in the Command Prompt, my *Adminu* account is still on Guest mode.

Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not the Guest Mode you are seeing, it is a list of the user names. Since you are logged in as administrator you have been already granted all privileges.